# Determine velocity vector on sloped surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity, geometry

A golf ball is launched at a speed *v* and launch angle, *β* . At some point the ball is located on the rim of a hole. The view from above looks as follows:

[image]

Vector *v* can be expressed in two components, *v<sub>x</sub>* and *v<sub>y</sub>*

$$ v_y = v \cdot \cos(\beta) $$

and

$$ v_x = v \cdot \sin(\beta) $$

If we look at the surface from a different angle, we see that the surface has a slope.
The slope of the green is equal to φ (along the y-axis).

[image]

*v<sub>v(ertical)</sub>* is perpendicular to the y-axis. As a result:

$$ v_v = v \cdot \cos(\beta) \cdot \sin(\varphi) $$

Let's assume now there is no slope across the y-axis (φ=0), but there is a slope across the x-axis, θ.

[image]

Following the same logic *v<sub>v</sub>* is perpendicular to the x-axis. As a result:

$$ v_v = -1 \cdot v \cdot \sin(\beta) \cdot \sin(\theta) $$

What is the formula of *v<sub>v</sub>* expressed in terms of both φ and θ? So, in the case that the surface is sloped/inclined across both the x- and y-axis?

*Edit*

With the help of @eli I know that I can write the following regarding the velocity vector:

$$\mathbf v_B= \left[ \begin {array}{c} v\sin \left( \beta \right) 
\\ v\cos \left( \beta \right) 
\\  0
\end {array} \right]
$$

When I rotate around the y-axis, I am actually changing θ, the slope across the x-axis:

$$\mathbf R_y = \left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos(\theta) \:\:\: 0 \:\:\: \sin(\theta)
\\ 0 \:\:\: 1 \:\:\: 0
\\  -\sin(\theta) \:\:\: 0 \:\:\: \cos(\theta)
\end {array} \right]
$$

Rotating around the y-axis:

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos(\theta) \:\:\: 0 \:\:\: \sin(\theta)
\\ 0 \:\:\: 1 \:\:\: 0
\\  -\sin(\theta) \:\:\: 0 \:\:\: \cos(\theta)
\end {array} \right] \cdot
\left[ \begin {array}{c} v\sin \left( \beta \right) 
\\ v\cos \left( \beta \right) 
\\  0
\end {array} \right]
=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} v\sin \left( \beta \right) \cos \left( \theta\right)
\\ v\cos \left( \beta \right) 
\\ -v\sin \left( \beta \right)\sin \left( \theta \right)
\end {array} \right]
$$

Next, I need to rotate around the z-axis using φ

$$\mathbf R_z = \left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos(\varphi) \:\:\: -\sin(\varphi) \:\:\: 0
\\ \sin(\varphi) \:\:\: \cos(\varphi) \:\:\: 0
\\  0 \:\:\: 0 \:\:\: 1
\end {array} \right]
$$

Combined this gives:

$$\mathbf v_I=\mathbf R_z(\varphi)\,\mathbf R_y(\theta) \mathbf v_B$$

Which is equal to:

$$\mathbf v_I = \left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos(\varphi) \:\:\: -\sin(\varphi) \:\:\: 0
\\ \sin(\varphi) \:\:\: \cos(\varphi) \:\:\: 0
\\  0 \:\:\: 0 \:\:\: 1
\end {array} \right]
\cdot
\left[ \begin {array}{c} v\sin \left( \beta \right) \cos \left( \theta\right)
\\ v\cos \left( \beta \right) 
\\ -v\sin \left( \beta \right)\sin \left( \theta \right)
\end {array} \right]
=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} v\sin(\beta)\cos(\theta)\cos(\varphi
) - v\cos(\beta)\sin(\varphi) 
\\ v\sin(\beta)\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi
) + v\cos(\beta)\cos(\varphi) 
\\ -v\sin \left( \beta \right)\sin \left( \theta \right)
\end {array} \right]
$$

Assuming the above is correct; what is in this case *v<sub>v</sub>*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the components of the velocity vector given in ball system are

$$\mathbf v_B= \left[ \begin {array}{c} v\sin \left( \beta \right) 
\\ v\cos \left( \beta \right) \\  0
\end {array} \right]
$$

to transformed  the components to inertial system you first rotate the velocity vector about y-axis with the rotation angle $~\theta~$ and then rotate the new vector about the x-axis with the angle $~\varphi~$ , you obtain:

$$\mathbf v_I=\mathbf R_x(\varphi)\,\mathbf R_y(\theta) \mathbf v_B$$

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Am I correct to assume that we actually use rotation angle  for the y-axis and  for z/x? I added your remarks to the question, but still struggling with the final answer. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Understood, but there is no  in my version of (). Is that correct or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I think the transformation is $~R_x(\varphi)\,R_y(\theta)~$

Comment: you obtain 
$~v_v=v\,\left(-\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \sin \left( \theta \right) \sin \left( 
\beta \right) +\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \cos \left( \beta \right)
\right)$

Comment: take a book in your hand (the axes are x and y) rotate it first about the y axis and then  about the new x axis, this is the "golf plane" right ?

Comment: yes, that's it. Boooom, thank you

Comment: final question; $$ v_h = ()y $$?

Comment: Yes you got 3 components x,y,z